# SuspendingTileService() is causing two errors on an empty class

Tags: android, wear-os, wear-os-tiles

I'm re-writing a wearOS android app. This app uses Horologist tiles. When I try to create the class to implement the tiles, I get the error:

`Class 'MainTile' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract val lifecycle: Lifecycle defined in com.google.android.horologist.tiles.SuspendingTileService`

The class:

```
package com.pyrosmart.[redacted].presentation

import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.wear.tiles.RequestBuilders
import androidx.wear.tiles.ResourceBuilders
import androidx.wear.tiles.TileBuilders
import com.google.android.horologist.tiles.ExperimentalHorologistTilesApi
import com.google.android.horologist.tiles.SuspendingTileService

@OptIn(ExperimentalHorologistTilesApi::class)
class MainTile : SuspendingTileService() {
    override suspend fun tileRequest(requestParams: RequestBuilders.TileRequest): Tile {
        return Tile.Builder()
            // create your tile here
            .build()
    }

    override suspend fun resourcesRequest(
        requestParams: RequestBuilders.ResourcesRequest
    ): ResourceBuilders.Resources = ResourceBuilders.Resources.Builder().setVersion("1").build()

}
```

I am using [this guide](https://google.github.io/horologist/tiles/#suspendingtileservice), which has worked for me before. The previous project also works and does not give this error.

I tried re-creating the class, and re-building but to no avail.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to "Fix" the issue by changing build.gradle to:

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.2.0'
    wear_compose_version = '1.0.0'
}
```